# How do I transpose observations into variables/columns?

Tags: r, dcast

I've got a data frame that looks something like this:

```
precinct, race, age, people
1001, black, 18-40, 1
1001, white, 18-40, 2
1001, hispanic, 18-40, 3
1001, asian, 18-40, 4
1001, black, 40 or older, 5
1001, white, 40 or older, 6
1001, hispanic, 40 or older, 7
1001, asian, 40 or older, 8
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
precinct, black, white, hispanic, asian, 18-40, 40 or older
1001, 6, 8, 10, 12, 10, 26
```

I've used `dcast`

```
dcast(
  data = mydataframe,
  formula = Precinct ~ race + age,
  fun.aggregate = sum,
  value.var = 'people'
)
```

but this does not produce my desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we create formula with `+` on the rhs of `~` it creates the combinations between those columns instead of having every single unique element from those columns.  In order to have the latter, we may need to `melt` to long format and then use `dcast` on the single column (assuming those columns are of the same type)

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(mydataframe), id.var = c('precinct', 'people')),
    precinct ~ value, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = 'people')
```

-output

```
Key: <precinct>
   precinct 18-40 40 or older asian black hispanic white
      <int> <int>       <int> <int> <int>    <int> <int>
1:     1001    10          26    12     6       10     8
```

---

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydataframe %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(race, age), names_to = NULL) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = people, values_fn = sum)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 × 7
  precinct black `18-40` white hispanic asian `40 or older`
     <int> <int>   <int> <int>    <int> <int>         <int>
1     1001     6      10     8       10    12            26
```

#### data

```
mydataframe <- structure(list(precinct = c(1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 
1001L, 1001L, 1001L), race = c("black", "white", "hispanic", 
"asian", "black", "white", "hispanic", "asian"), age = c("18-40", 
"18-40", "18-40", "18-40", "40 or older", "40 or older", "40 or older", 
"40 or older"), people = 1:8), row.names = c(NA, -8L), 
class = "data.frame")
```